# How much time do I have to notice astronomical events?

Tags: kittens-game

I'll frequently leave [Kittens Game](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/) running and come back to find several rare astronomical events have occurred.  Once or twice they happen while I'm watching, and there's an "observe" button which awards me science.  Presumably this button goes away after some period of time, which is why I never see it for the events that occur while I'm not watching.

How much time do I have between the noticing of a rare astronomical event and the loss of the capability to observe it?

Comment: It is less then 70 days. I saw in summer 80 days there was something, while I left at summer 10 days.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the code, in `calendar.js`:

```
var seconds = 60;
this.observeTimeout = setTimeout(dojo.hitch(this, observeTimeout), seconds * 1000);
```

Thus, you have sixty seconds to hit the button, lest the event pass you by.

Another event appearing in that window immediately ends the 60 seconds though (but still process the auto harvest chance if applicable). Observatories give a auto harvest chance, and later a research makes all events auto harvest.

Comment: So it is independent if you pause the game, or not? That sucks

Comment: @Mathias I'm not 100% on that part, which is why I didn't mention pausing; the pause button may well be pausing all the dojo processing, which would pause the events. I'll be looking into it tonight, hopefully.

Comment: Okay. In case I see the observe button again, I will try it, and comment it here. In that way just one of us has to lose science :P

Comment: Negative. The observe button disappeared on me while the game was paused.

Answer (score 0):

There occurred a rare astronomical event at day 49, and the observe button disappeared at day 71, but from the other answer it seems to be unrelated to the days passed ingame.